# Azure Event Hub | What happens if "Size of compacted event hub" quota is being exceeded?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Listed on [Azure Event Hub quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas?source=recommendations#basic-vs-standard-vs-premium-vs-dedicated-tiers):

| Limit | Standard |
| --- | --- |
| Size of compacted event hub | 1 GB per partition |

"Compacted" refers to [Log compaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/log-compaction) here

What happens, if the quota is being exceeded?

Answer (score 1):

@Markus Schulte

So,for the above svenario a few things might happen. First off, log compaction, **which retains only the latest version of an event for a specific key,** could kick in to keep within the allowed size. Older, non-latest versions might be removed.

If this goes on consistently as worst case, you might experience **rejected write operations**. The system could start throttling to prevent excessive usage.